# How to obtain confidence of extracted text from pytesseract.image_to_boxes

Tags: python, python-tesseract

I am using pytesseract.image_to_boxes because I need to extract all details from the text but I need it at character level. I obtain the text of the character, left, bottom, right, top and page. But I also need confidence and it seems that this function does not provide it.
I know I can use image_to_data to obtain confidence as well, but this is given for the whole word and I need it for each character separately. Is there any way of obtaining it?
Thanks in advance

Example:

string in img = 168

`pytesseract.image_to_boxes(img, output_type=pytesseract.Output.DICT)`

What I am obtaining:

```
{'char': ['1', '6', '8'], 
'left': [15, 87, 177], 
'bottom': [0, 0, 0], 
'right': [66, 162, 252], 
'top': [136, 135, 135], 
'page': [0, 0, 0]}
```

desired result:

```
{'char': ['1', '6', '8'], 
**'conf': [99.99, 87.86, 78.55],**
'left': [15, 87, 177], 
'bottom': [0, 0, 0], 
'right': [66, 162, 252], 
'top': [136, 135, 135], 
'page': [0, 0, 0]}
```